# Can't get audio to play using jQuery.each()

Tags: jquery, audio, each

I'm trying to get audio files associated with specific words to play successively with the individual words  being hilited while the audio is playing and with brief delays between the events. I want this process to be repeated for each word in the page. This is part of  the html:

```
    <p id="pathVar">/templates/beez_20/audio/word_sets/word_set1/</p>
    <p class="wordSetNum">1</p>
    <div id="word_learning">
      <p id="title">Word Learning 1</p>
      <div id="centering">     
        <div id="left_col"> 
          <p class="word_learn">1<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e1">the</span> คำนำหน้านามเจาะจง </span></p>
          <p class="word_learn">2<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e2">and</span>    และ </span></p>
          <p class="word_learn">3<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e3">of</span>       ของ </span></p>
          <p class="word_learn">4<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e4">to</span>       ถึง </span></p>
          <p class="word_learn">5<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e5">a</span>        หนึ่ง </span></p>
```

etc. And here is the js:

```
    "use strict";
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    alert("1st");
      jQuery("div#word_learning").click(function (evnt) {
      alert("2nd");
        var  pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
          setNum = document.getElementById("setNum").innerHTML, 
          audioElement = document.createElement("audio"),
          audioType = Modernizr.audio.ogg? ".ogg": ".mp3";
        jQuery("p.word_learn").each(function(i)  {
          jQuery(this).css("color : red;");
          audioElement.src = pathVar+"b"+setNum+"e"+i+audioType;
          jQuery(this).delay(250);
          audioElement.load();    
          audioElement.play();     
          jQuery(this).delay(500);
          jQuery(this).css("color : black;");
        });
      });
    });
```

The first alert displays when the page is loaded, but the second does not when the initial word in the list is clicked. I would be grateful for any help. in

Comment: You are using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) wrong. Use it like this: `jQuery(this).css('color','black')`

Comment: Thanks for that. I also picked up the mismatch between html "wordSetNum" and the js variable "setNum". Changed that too. And now the audio of the second last word on the page is played, some progress!!